# Ionic css files empty in second sass output directory

Tags: sass, ionic-framework, gulp, gulp-sass

I try to add a second sass 'cycle' to my ionic project. Here is the relevant part of my **gulpfile.js**

```
var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss'],
  themesass: ['./www/data/theme/css/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass','themesass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('themesass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./www/data/theme/css/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/data/theme/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/data/theme/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.themesass, ['themesass']);
});
```

On changing **style.css** I get following output in terminal:

```
File changed: www/data/theme/css/style.scss
[12:07:03] Starting 'themesass'...
[12:07:03] Finished 'themesass' after 14 ms
CSS changed:  www/data/theme/css/style.css
CSS changed:  www/data/theme/css/style.min.css
```

Both files (**style.css** and **style.min.css**) stay empty though. What am I missing?